# Define variables in OctoberCMS so could do math operations

Tags: php, laravel, variables, math, octobercms

I made query and have in DB table with prefix and formula.
I am using OctoberCMS that is based on Laravel

```
$formulas = Product::join('pivot', 'products.id', '=', 'pivot.product_id')
             ->join('formulas', 'pivot.formulas_id', '=', 'formulas.id')
             ->select('formulas.prefix','formulas.formula')
             ->get();

$prefix = $formulas->lists('prefix');
extract($prefix);
$prefix2 = implode(' $', $prefix);

$formula = $formulas->lists('formula');
if (preg_match('([aA-zZ])', $formula)) {
    $formula2 = implode(' $', $formula);
    $formula2 = get_class($formula);
}
else {

}
```

I made query and have in DB table with prefix and formula:

Prefix Formula

```
e 2a-b-c

f 4a*4

h a*2
```

I have already defined

```
$a = 30;
$b = 2;
$c = 5;
```

I want to define every prefix as variable so could do math functions:

```
$e = 2 $a - $b - $c;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
$arrPrefix = array('e' => '2a-b-c', 'h' => '4a*4', 'f' => 'a*2');

foreach ($arrPrefix as $key => $v) {
    $result = "";
    for( $i = 0; $i <= strlen($v); $i++ ) {
            $char = substr( $v, $i, 1 );
            if( ctype_alpha( $char ) ) 
            { 
                $result .= "$". $char; 
            }
            else
            {
               $result .= $char; 
            }
        }

    $output[] = "$".$key.'='.$result;
}
```

Output:
Now you have print_r($output); the result is,

```
Array
(
    [0] => $e=2$a-$b-$c
    [1] => $h=4$a*4
    [2] => $f=$a*2
)
```